# Find and replace all numbers after a string value and increment each one

Tags: regex, awk, sed, replace

I am trying to see if I can achieve a find/replace and increment an integer value in a couple of lines. To explain, I have the following text:

```
&sr=1240000000000&type=game&scoreA=x&scoreB=y&
&sr=1150000000000&type=game&scoreB=x&scoreB=y&
&sr=1270000000000&type=game&scoreC=x&scoreB=y&
&sr=1010000000000&type=game&scoreD=x&scoreB=y&
```

I want to replace ONLY the number after `sr=` till... `&` so for example as shown in bold:

> &sr=**1240000000000**&type=game&scoreA=x&scoreB=y&

All numbers to be replaced and incremented by `10000` for each subsequent one found...

So ideally when I use a script as follows (Taking 2 args, first is value to replace to, and the input file):

**./script.sh 1500000000000 file.txt**

it should replace all as:

```
&sr=1500000010000&type=game&scoreA=x&scoreB=y&
&sr=1500000020000&type=game&scoreB=x&scoreB=y&
&sr=1500000030000&type=game&scoreC=x&scoreB=y&
&sr=1500000040000&type=game&scoreD=x&scoreB=y&
```

I put together a python script to achieve this but was wondering if anyone can advise me on doing this in a 1-3 liner script, maybe using AWK/SED. My python script is kinda long.

Comment: Can you show us your work so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use this `awk`:

```
awk -v n='10000' -v s='1500000000000' 'sub("sr=[0-9]+&", "sr=" (s+i+n) "\\&"){
i+=n} 1' file
```

```
&sr=1500000010000&type=game&scoreA=x&scoreB=y&
&sr=1500000020000&type=game&scoreB=x&scoreB=y&
&sr=1500000030000&type=game&scoreC=x&scoreB=y&
&sr=1500000040000&type=game&scoreD=x&scoreB=y&
```

Comment: But what happens if the value 1240000000000 is not known. It may be different values, I just gave an example. I edited the question to make it clear sorry.:)

Comment: What i mean is: we will pass `1500000000000` to the script as input argument. But the value in the text file e.g. `sr=1240000000000&` can vary on each line so hardcoding it in script to find it and replace it might not work.

Comment: In the file we will have random numbers after `sr=xxx`. The script will update the first one with a value we pass to script, for e.g. `1500000000000` and there-onwards it will increment each one after that with +10000.

Comment: Yerp, I think since you answered first but both answers are exactly what I was looking for! - thanks alot.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a bash script, awk can handle this on its own

```
awk -v num=1500000000000 '{num += 10000; sub(/^&sr=[0-9]+/, "\\&sr=" num)}1' file > tmpfile
mv tmpfile file
```

Comment: Looks good. Any idea how I apply this change to the file? Currently it prints to console. :)